# JavaFX layout based on percentage of window size

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I need to create a Layout in JavaFX with 3 labels. Each label should be centered horizontally. The first should be placed 1/4 of the way down the window, the second should be halfway down (i.e. centered vertically) and the third should be 3/4 of the way down.

The labels should keep their relative positions if the window is resized.

It seems pretty simple, but I can't figure out how to do it. I tried with a VBox, but there doesn't seem to be a way to have fine control over the vertical placement. I then looked at AnchorPane, but couldn't see how to do this.

Can someone show me an easy way to do this either with FXML or programmatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with a `GridPane` (there may be other ways). Fill it with four rows and one column, and use `RowConstraints` to make each row the same height and to align the labels at the bottom of each row. Use a `ColumnConstraints` object to center the labels horizontally.

SSCCE:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.VPos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LayoutExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        GridPane root = new GridPane();
        int numRows = 4 ;
        for (int i = 0 ; i < numRows ; i++) {
            RowConstraints rc = new RowConstraints();
            rc.setPercentHeight(100.0 / numRows);
            rc.setValignment(VPos.BOTTOM);
            root.getRowConstraints().add(rc);
        }
        ColumnConstraints cc = new ColumnConstraints();
        cc.setHalignment(HPos.CENTER);
        cc.setPercentWidth(100);
        root.getColumnConstraints().add(cc);

        for (int row = 0; row < 3 ; row++) {
            Label label = new Label("Label "+(row+1));
            root.add(label, 0, row);
        }

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I hadn't considered using a GridPane, but now in retrospect, it's the obvious choice. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's the layout pane that gives you the most control over positioning: JavaFX's equivalent of Swing's `GridBagLayout`, if you have used Swing.

Answer (score 1):

The `FXML` based approach and using a `VBox` instead of a `GridPane`would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="CENTER">

    <Label text="Label 1" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS"> 
        <maxHeight><Double fx:constant="MAX_VALUE" /></maxHeight>
    </Label>
    <Label text="Label 2" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS"> 
        <maxHeight><Double fx:constant="MAX_VALUE" /></maxHeight>
    </Label>
    <Label text="Label 3" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS"> 
        <maxHeight><Double fx:constant="MAX_VALUE" /></maxHeight>
    </Label>
</VBox>
```

This code may not like like this, when generated by SceneBuilder, because I use the [e(fx)clipse](https://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/index.html) internal DSL [FXGraph](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Efxclipse/Tooling/FXGraph) to generate it.

***EDIT***

As @James_D suggested (see comment below), this might not be the solution fitting at any time. So. A minor update to the `FXML` from above would be to use `Region`s as "spacers" around your `Label`s.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Region?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="CENTER">
    <Region VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS"> 
        <maxHeight><Double fx:constant="MAX_VALUE" /></maxHeight>
    </Region>
    <Label text="Label 1"/> 
    <Region VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS"> 
        <maxHeight><Double fx:constant="MAX_VALUE" /></maxHeight>
    </Region>
    <Label text="Label 2"/> 
    <Region VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS"> 
        <maxHeight><Double fx:constant="MAX_VALUE" /></maxHeight>
    </Region>
    <Label text="Label 3"/> 
    <Region VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS"> 
        <maxHeight><Double fx:constant="MAX_VALUE" /></maxHeight>
    </Region>
</VBox>
```

This should a more flexible solution.

Comment: I tried using a `VBox`, but I think the proportions come out wrong. Each `Label` is 1/3 the height of the `VBox`, and the labels are centered, so the top label is 1/6 the way down the screen, not 1/4 (and similarly the bottom label is at 5/6).

Comment: You might be right. In this case you would need to use `Region`s as "spacers" around the `Label`. I will update my answer accordingly and add this option.

Answer (score 1):

The ConstrainedGridPane class below helps doing this.
In your 4 label case you'd extend it like this:

```
 public class LabelPane extends ConstrainedGridPane() {
   public LabelPane() {
     // ... setup you labels
     // hgap=0 - 1 column using 100%
     super.fixColumnSizes(0,100);
     // vgap=5 - 4 columns using 25% each ...
     super.fixRowSizes(5, 25,25,25,25);
   }
 }
```

**ConstrainedGridPane source code**

```
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints;

/**
 * a GridPane with Column and RowConstraints
 * @author wf
 *
 */
public class ConstrainedGridPane extends GridPane {


  /**
   * fix the columnSizes to the given column Width
   * @param colWidths
   */
  public void fixColumnSizes(int hGap,int... colWidths) {
    this.setHgap(hGap);
    // Setting columns size in percent
    for (int colWidth : colWidths) {
      ColumnConstraints column = new ColumnConstraints();
      column.setPercentWidth(colWidth);
      getColumnConstraints().add(column);
    }
  }

  /**
   * fix the rowSizes to the given rowHeights
   * @param rowHeights
   */
  public void fixRowSizes(int vGap,int... rowHeight) {
    this.setVgap(vGap);
    for (int rowWidth : rowHeight) {
      RowConstraints rowc = new RowConstraints();
      rowc.setPercentHeight(rowWidth);
      getRowConstraints().add(rowc);
    }

    // grid.setPrefSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT); // Default width and
    // height
    this.setMaxSize(Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
  }
}
```